# Wiremock standalone JSON response.ok equals false never reached

Tags: json, fetch, wiremock

I am trying to test different fetch failure scenarios for a JS app using Wiremock standalone with JSON mappings.

```js
try {
  const response = await fetch('/api', options); // 1

  if (response.ok) {
    // do something with a successful response
  } else {
    throw new Error('response not ok'); // 2
  }
} catch (error) {
  // log the error // 3
}
```

When I [simulate bad response failures](http://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults/#bad-responses) as per the Wiremock docs it fails at the fetch call (1) and triggers the catch (3).

```json
{
  "request": {
    "urlPath": "/api",
    "method": "ANY"
  },
  "response": {
    "fault": "RANDOM_DATA_THEN_CLOSE"
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PUT",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "x-csrf-token, content-type, pragma, cache-control",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
      "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
      "x-frame-options": "DENY",
      "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
    }
  }
}
```

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) response.ok is a read only boolean 2XX, but if I set the status to 408 response.ok is still true.

```json
{
  "request": {
    "urlPath": "/api",
    "method": "ANY"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 408,
    "jsonBody": {},
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't yet found a combination of status codes/faults with wiremock to actually trigger the !response.ok error (2). We are getting logs from our UI to our production server which is telling us the !response.ok branch is being hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [fetch MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch):

> A fetch() promise only rejects when a network error is encountered
> (which is usually when there’s a permissions issue or similar). A
> fetch() promise does not reject on HTTP errors (404, etc.). Instead, a
> then() handler must check the Response.ok and/or Response.status
> properties.

So, the simplest test you can do to reach `response.ok === false` is to invoke it against unknown `URL` to force server to return `404`.

For example, let's test this functionality using `SO` and this question. You can fetch it like below:

```js
async function fetchMe() {
  let resp = await fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64319800");
  if (resp.ok) {
      console.log("Question exists!");
  } else {
      console.log("Question does not exist!");
  }
};
fetchMe();
```

When we add some text at the end of the `URL`, `SO` should return `404`:

```js
async function fetchUnknown() {
  let resp = await fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64319800UNKNOWN");
  if (resp.ok) {
      console.log("Question exists!");
  } else {
      console.log("Question does not exist!");
  }
};
fetchUnknown();
```

Comment: Thanks Michal. You highlighted the first rule of debugging: if in doubt go from the basic scenario to the more complicated. Our options object is actually:
`{ credentials: 'include', ...fetchOptions, ...headers, signal: abortController.signal }`
Which was causing the error, and skipping to the catch block. Nothing to do with Wiremock or how we were checking for response.ok